# How to insert values in google cloud dataprep

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

I have mismatched ZIP codes in Dataprep. I need to add two digits to columns where it was entered improperly.

In Dataprep I get a suggestion to replace:

`'{start}{digit}{3}{end}' with ' '`

In the replace dialog I can only put a string, not `'{start}{digit}{3}{end}'` because it reads it as text. How do I replace:

`'{start}{digit}{3}{end}'` with `12 + '{start}{digit}{3}{end}'`

Replacing or inserting, either would work but I haven't found a way to insert either.

Any help at all? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Merge Transform](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Merge-Transform_57344642). It allows two merge several columns or values into a new column, also allowing the possibility to insert a delimiter between the values that you are merging.

From your question, I understand that you want to turn a data value like `345` into `12345`, i.e. attaching `12` as a prefix. To do so, you can run the `merge()` formula just like this:

```
merge(['12',zip])
```

In this case, `zip` is just the name of the column that you want to merge with the value `12`. Write the name of your column in your specific case.

The image below shows the results of running the `merge()` formula.

[image]

---

***UPDATE:***

Given the case that you have both correct and incorrect ZIP codes in your data, you can apply a [conditional logic function `IF`](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/IF-Function_57344759) in order to determine which formula to apply to your data. The `IF()` function works like this:

```
IF(test_expression, true_expression, false_expression)
```

So in your case, you should evaluate over the length of the items in the column and only add `12` *when there are exactly three digits in the row*, as you said in your comment. The formula I used is the following one:

```
if(len(zip) == 3, merge(['12',zip]), zip)
```

And the results (compared when using `IF()` [*right_new_zip* column] and when not using it [*wrong_new_zip* column]) are these ones:

[image]

Finally, let me refer you to this nice [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Wrangle-Language_57344628) where you will find all the information you need about the language used in Dataprep and the functions you can find useful, categorized by type (Logical, Aggregate, String, Date, etc.).

Comment: Yes, that's that I want to do. However the column contains correct zip codes and incorrect ones. Is there a way to only merge when there are exactly three digits in the row and not 5?